# How to avoid circular imports?

Tags: python, dynamic, python-import

**Overview**

EDIT: ALTERED FOLLOWING @IjonTichy's [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488831/5414155)

I am trying to import two variables across files. I have a GUI file using tkinter and another file storing a number of variables. The problem specifically is that the GUI file has a `tk.Entry` field, so the value of the variable is dynamic and changes depending on what is input. I would rather not use a button here. I am using a `tk.StringVar` object to hold the data (perhaps clearer in the code below.

The second variable is just a float based on a calculation so pretty easy to assign there. The problem I am having is this file requires the `tk.StringVar` value to perform a calculation.

**What I have tried**

So firstly I tried simply taking variables from each file, using `import [filename]` and then `[filename].[variable]` when I needed to call it. Predictably this caused an error due to circular imports, which makes sense.

Subsequently, I tried dumping all this data into a config file and allowing both files to pull from this third file but that also results in the same.

**Code**

> vitals.py

```
from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal

birth = date(1992, 6, 22)
today = date.today()

age = today.year - birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birth.month, birth.day))
weight = 0
height = 177.5
activity = 1.2
#tdee = bmr * activity

def bmr(weight, height, age):
    return Decimal(((10 * float(weight)) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5))
```

> GUI.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import config

app = tk.Tk()
defaultColour = "beige"

mainFrame = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, bg=defaultColour)
mainFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

weightLabel = tk.Label(master=mainFrame,text='weight', bg=defaultColour)
weightLabel.pack()

weightVar = tk.DoubleVar() #NEW LINE

weightEntry = tk.Entry(mainFrame, textvariable=weightVar)
weightEntry.pack()
weightEntry.focus_set()

vitals.weight = weightVar.get()
print(vitals.bmr(vitals.weight, vitals.height, vitals.age))

ageLabel = tk.Label(master=mainFrame,text='age: ' + str(config.age), bg=defaultColour)
ageLabel.pack()

app.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: app.destroy())

app.mainloop()
```

**Question**

I am at a bit of a loss as to how I might structure this properly. So would someone be able to tell me where I am going wrong? Alternatively if you could point me in the direction of some resources that teach good coding structure. This is my first time coding an application so apologies for the inanity of this question.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump the config.py file.
initialize your variables in vitals.py and change the variables from GUI.py.

i.e. inside vitals.py:

```
weight = 0
```

and inside GUI.py

```
import vitals
vitals.weight = weightVar.get()
```

Edit:

the new problem you now have is because your value of bmr depends on weight.

when you do

```
import vitals
```

bmr gets calculated with initialized value.
When you want to have bmr calculated dynamically you need to change it to a function. So in vitals.py:

```
def bmr(weight, height, age):
    return Decimal(((10 * float(weight)) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5))
```

And then you call it from GUI.py:

```
import vitals
vitals.weight = weightVar.get()
print(vitals.bmr(vitals.weight, vitals.height, vitals.age))
```

edit2:

you need to do this for all values that are dependent on other variables

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just tried this and it resolved the circular imports so that's really helpful. However, it is still not working functionally unfortunately. So, if I do ```print(vitals.bmr)``` in ```GUI.py```, it performs the calculation at the intialized value and not the updated one. The same occurs if I do ```print(bmr)``` in ```vitals.py```. I have updated the OP to reflect changes. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your updated answer. I implemented your changes (and commented out any dependent values that weren't relevant here) but I am now getting a ValueError. Specifically, ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''```. Sorry for all the questions. ```weight``` is initialized to 0 in ```vitals.py``` but it seems to be setting it to ```Null```, as far as I understand it? OP also updated accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the above. I have altered ```StringVar``` to ```DoubleVar``` but now I have returned to the previous problem of ```weight``` sticking at the intialized value of 0

Comment: The problem you have is a bit more fundamental. What you are doing at the moment is basically static. You initialize some values and then do calculation based on these values. What you want is calculations based on user input. Therefore you need a way to trigger the calculation after the user inputted its weight. For this you could introduce a button in your gui that triggers the bmr function and prints the return value. I haven't used tkinter until now so i can't help you with this.

Comment: Hi, no problem and thank you for your response. I figured the solution might be a bit more conceptual so I'll work on refactoring the code as you suggest. I will mark this as the solution as it essentially resolved most of the problems I had.